# C# MySQL NotScalarQuery method gives error on creating function or Procedures

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm running this code :

```
          public bool notscalarquery(string s)
    {
        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(s, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                CloseConnection();
                return true;

            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                CloseConnection();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

```
                     if (ConnectionToMySQL.notscalarquery(query) == true)
                     {
                        MessageBox.Show("Statement executed successfully!");
                        return true;
                     }
```

query values is =

```
                  "DELIMITER $$ \n CREATE FUNCTION `new_functionewqd` () \n RETURNS INTEGER \n BEGIN \n RETURN 1; \n END $$"
```

I tried also query.Replace("\n"," ") but doesn't work.
The strange thing is that if I paste this on workbench editor:

```
                                DELIMITER $$ 
                                CREATE FUNCTION `new_functionewqd3124` () 
                                RETURNS INTEGER 
                                BEGIN  RETURN 1;
                                END $$
```

Works!! How is possible?

Comment: What is the error? Just a guess but, try removing the DELIMITER  $$  ... $$ from the query value.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
string cmdText = @"CREATE FUNCTION `new_functionewqd` () RETURNS INTEGER 
                   BEGIN 
                      RETURN 1; 
                   END";
```

I think that the DELIMITER $$ is understood only in the Workbench editor (or similar tools).

Comment: doens't work, in mysql i have to use delimiter, or the command will be cut

Comment: What version of MySql?